# Ghost Blog/NodeJS - How to create server side GET to remote endpoint to populate specific theme

Tags: server, request, blogs, ghost

I have a ghost blog application up and running on NodeJS. A recent request is to make several server side calls to a public endpoints, parse xml response and populate resulting HMTL within Ghost Blog theme.

As I am new to ghost/node, I'm trying to get the high level on how this would be accomplished and/or propagated thru my ghost application. Been reading some of the Ghost documentation but still not entirely sure on next steps or if even possible. Any help or pointers on where to start would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very broad question that needs to be broken down.   Question 1 How do you trigger a simple get request to API.  Question 2.  How to parse the xml response to an html file.  Question 3. How to save an html file snippet, inside of a ghost theme, and store that somewhere. (do you keep persistance with DB? or do you just localStorage the theme) Question 4.  How to fetch/parse newly created theme pieces to display back to user, on their theme.(you'll likely have to override alot of internal settings)   All of this, will require some knowledge of nodeJS and definitely javascript.

Comment: thanks for your response KyleK, agreed this is a broad topic, looks like i have further digging todo.